# How to kill all parallel Bash/Linux tasks on condition of single instance

Tags: linux, bash, function, parallel-processing, kill-process

I have a parallelised Bash function:

```
#!/bin/bash

touch out.txt
vals=$(seq 1 1 20)
task(){
    echo $1 >> out.txt
    x=$(wc -l out.txt | cut -d' ' -f 1) #read current length of file
    if [ $x > 5 ]
    then
    echo $x #NB prints even if <5!!
    KILL_ALL_JOBS_HERE_ON_IF_THEN_CONDITION
    fi
}

export -f task

echo $vals | xargs -P2 -I'{}' -d' ' bash -c 'task "$1"' bash {}
```

The function starts to echo the twenty values to a single text file. However, when the file is longer than 5 lines, I would like all processes/instances to stop and not process anymore values from the variable. How can I do it? (NB a minor issue, the if-then statement is also weird - it echoes the processed value, $x, irrespective of whether it's >5).

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) finds several problems with the code.

Answer (score 5):

> [ $x > 5 ]

is the same as:

```
[ $x ] > 5
```

it redirects the output of `[` command to a file named `5`. Just like `echo > 5`

You want:

```
[ "$x" -gt 5 ]
```

---

> ```
>  KILL_ALL_JOBS_HERE_ON_IF_THEN_CONDITION
> ```

If you are using GNU xargs, them from man xargs:

> If any invocation of the command exits with a status of 255,
> xargs will stop immediately without reading any further input.
> An error message is issued on stderr when this happens.

Just `exit 255`.

Comment: Fantastic thanks. Silly me, I knew -gt for >. But the exit tip is a big help